# How to add fixed buttons above a ListView android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to have two buttons top of a listview. If I scroll below the listview I want that the buttons stay at top. I searched through many solutions on stackoverflow however I could not find the exact one for my case.

My layout xml(mainlayout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/latest_news_button" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tracked_news_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The graphical layout produced is just what I wanted:

[image: graphical layout:]

Here is my code to use this layout, in case I might fail to bind the Java code to layout;

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

Button latestButton;
Button trackedButton;
ListView lv = null;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    latestButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    latestButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Latest Button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    trackedButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    trackedButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tracked Button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    this.lv = getListView();
    String[] values = new String[]{"asdfa","qwerqwer","banbn"};
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(BilTrackerMainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, values));

}
```

however when this activity is called from my other activity my app unfortunately closed. LogCat says:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

But I try adding `lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);` instead of `this.lv = getListView();`. I could not solve this issue. 
I am aware of `ListView#addHeaderView` but I want to solve my particular problem with using this kind of layout.

Comment: Why you just use RelativeLayout?

Comment: Your problem is not with the buttons, but with the id you chose for your `ListView` see answers below regarding `@android:id/list`

Comment: Thank you all, just changing my bad line to android:id="@android:id/list" seem to work. If someone provide a source for these kind of knowledge lack, I will appreciate that also. Now my top buttons are ok, but my list items does not work. I am working on them.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1` when you aren't using an expandable list?

Comment: Yes you are right. I deleted the expandable part and changed the last 2 lines of my code to this: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your listview id to   `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: There is also an explanation [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listactivity_layout)

Answer (score 1):

Use a RelativeLayout.  Place the second button to the right of the first button using layout_toRightOf then place the listview beneath button one using layout_below.  Something like this (I haven't tested it, apologies for any typos)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/latest_news_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/tracked_news_button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to android and for now i will stick with linear layout. I tested your code and when you change ListView's android:id like Dipak and stated before, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xml you are looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FF394952">


 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_AddMore"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/newItem"
    android:textColor="#FF394952"/>
 </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/game_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And when you design Activity for this dont use List activity directly use Activity and set adapter on the ListView.

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.game_list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ALBUM_NAME);

    lv.setAdapter(listItem);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This will work, but this is just a different way to achieve the same end result. When using ListActivity, use the correct id on the ListView.

Comment: What you want to say? What the problem now

Answer (score 0):

Use below xml file for that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/mLlayout1" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/latest_news_button" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tracked_news_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mLlayout1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now it works, but using a RelativeLayout is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I am using Relativelayout to solve the problem of this line "If I scroll below the listview I want that the buttons stay at top. "

Answer (score 0):

Create FrameLayout with [your ListView] and [LinearLayout with your buttons].

Do once something like this within onCreate()

```
LinearLayout myButtons = ...;
myButtons.bringToFront();
```

So, your ContentView will have a FrameLayout with two child, one of those is in foreground.

That's all. Hope it helped))